# Is using volatile reference guarranty that read operations will not be reordered?

Tags: c++, reference, volatile

Suppose there is a `char* buffer` which points to some address in [SHMEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHMEM). First and second 8 bytes of the `buffer` contain correspondingly `counter1` and `counter2` unsigned 64 bit integers after them in the buffer there is a `message` with length `n`. Now let's look at the following 2 pieces of code:

first:

```
uint64_t counter1 = *((uint64_t*)(buffer));
memcpy(buffer_for_message, buffer + 2 * sizeof(uint64_t), n);
uint64_t counter2 = *((uint64_t*)(buffer)+1);
```

second:

```
volatile uint64_t& counter1_ref = *((uint64_t*)(buffer));
volatile uint64_t& counter2_ref = *((uint64_t*)(buffer)+1);
uint64_t counter1 = counter1_ref;
memcpy(buffer_for_message, buffer + 2 * sizeof(uint64_t), n);
uint64_t counter2 = counter2_ref;
```

Questions:

1. Is the order of reading memory blocks for `counter1`, `counter2` and the `message` by the processor undefined in case of the first piece of code?
2. If the answer for the first question is "yes", is the second code makes the order defined (i.e. `counter1`, then the `message` and then `counter2`)?

Comment: Please refrain from using terminology like *shmem* - how can I answer the question if such seemingly vital info is not clearly called out?

Comment: @JohannGerell, shmem is a very well-defined term. What's unclear about it?

Comment: Also I think shmem is not important for the answer. I just mentioned that just in case there are some issues for shmems.

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan, shmem is VERY important. Without shmem the answer would be different :)

Comment: @SergeyA: Now it's clear - added the proper definition

Comment: @JohannGerell, it was clear even without it. You do not add definitions for volatile or memcpy? It is the same level of definness.

Comment: @SergeyA: No it's not

Comment: @SergeyA: _"You do not add definitions for volatile or memcpy? It is the same level of definness"_ - not at all, where in the standard is "shmem" mentioned?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i guess, it would depend on tags :) In C++ world it is not, I do agree. If someone to add a proper 'multithreading' tag, it would be well-defined.

Comment: @JohannGerell, see my answer to LRiO. Without 'multithreading' tag (which I thought is there) it is not well-defined. Agreed.

Comment: @SergeyA: `volatile` has nothing to do with multithreading

Comment: @JohannGerell, who said it does? I did not. It is just that you usually care about reordering when you are dealing with multi(threading/processing).

Comment: @Johann: We were talking about SHMEM's "definedness". At least, I thought we were.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Mhm, yes. I started out that way.

Comment: None of you - including OP - are using the term SHMEM correctly according to the Wikipedia entry. If you want to reason about Cray SHMEM or OpenSHMEM semantics, see the man pages and specification, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the order is defined even for the first case. Here is why.

- Compiler can not reorder those instructions since there is a call to memcpy() in between them. Granted, memcpy could be intrinsic, but in this case it should see the same memory region affected.
- CPU will not reorder since buffer is in shared memory.

However, both examples have a problem - a violation of strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Is there a link which proofs that read/write access to shmem are not reordered?

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan, ok, now I want the definiton of shmem! :) You mean something created with shmget? Than read-writes are not reordered because it would violate the idea of shmem :)

Answer (score 3):

`volatile` in itself, as per the C++ standard, has nothing to do with reordering. Some compilers offer acquire and release semantics as an extension when `volatile` is used, but that is non-standard.